# How to require the owner of smart contract to approve the execution of a function

Tags: solidity, web3js, ethers.js, smart-contract-wallets

Please how can I add the intervention of a 3rd account that approves the execution of a function?

**Example :**
Bob wants to execute function F, but it won't be executed unless Alice comes in and checks the data sent and approves it on the smart contract.

Answer (score 0):

You could have something like :

```
contract Example{
  // Those are the parameters of the function to execute
  struct Params{
    uint a;
    uint b;
  }
  // We use a mapping(uint => ) because it's essentially impossible to delete an 
  // entry from an array in solidity while keeping the elements in-place. 
  mapping(uint => Params) public queued;
  uint nextToQueue;
  // This contains the logic to run
  function funcToRun(uint a, uint b) internal {
    //Logic
  }
  // This is the function that Bob calls, it sends Bob an index that they can submit to Alice for review
  function queueTransaction(uint a, uint b) public returns(uint index) {
    index = nextToQueue++; //NB: this stores the current value of nextToQueue in index and then increments it, as opposed to ++nextToQueue which would do it the other way around (not what we want here)
    Params memory toQueue = new Params(a, b);
    queued[index] = toQueue;
  }
  // This is the function Alice (the owner) calls to actually run the transaction 
  function executeTransaction(uint index) public onlyOwner {
    Params memory toExecute = queued[index];
    require(toExecute.a != 0 || toExecute.b != 0, "invalid index"); // An uninitialized slot in the mapping would return all 0s. Problem, if we need 0 to be a valid parameter a workaround is needed. In a real world case, `Params` would most likely include Bob's address anyways, so you can check for just that
    funcToRun(toExecute.a, toExecute.b);
    delete queued[index];
  }
}
```

If any of this is unclear to you, feel free to ask questions in comments.

Comment: thank you all for your answers. The problem is that I want the approval to be instantaneous and done automatically with a script and the mnemonic phrase.

Comment: With @Ethan approchach, send the data to a backend, verify it, generate the signature, send it back to the user so they can call `execute`. With my approach, have `queueTransaction` emit an event, catch that event in the backend, verify the data and call `executeTransaction` (not instantaneous, there is gonna be a few blocks delay between `queueTransaction` and `executeTransaction`

Answer (score 0):

Alice need signature the data, function will execute successfully.

verify signature demo: https://solidity-by-example.org/signature

```
function excute(bytes calldata data, bytes calldata signature){
    _verify(data, signature);
    _excute(data);
}
```

Comment: thank you all for your answers. The problem is that I want the approval to be instantaneous and done automatically with a script and the mnemonic phrase.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a modifier in your smart contract that requires the approval of a third account before a function can be executed.

```
contract MyContract {
  address public owner;
  address public alice;
  address public bob;
  bool public approved;
   constructor(address _alice, address _bob) {
    owner = msg.sender;
    alice = _alice;
    bob = _bob;
  }
   modifier onlyApproved() {
    require(msg.sender == bob && approved, "Function can only be executed by Bob after approval from Alice");
    _;
  }
   function F() public onlyApproved {
    // Function code goes here
  }
   function approve() public {
    require(msg.sender == alice, "Approval can only be given by Alice");
    approved = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you all for your answers. The problem is that I want the approval to be instantaneous and done automatically with a script and the mnemonic phrase.